# Find the integral of $\int {{2 \over {\sqrt x (x - 4)}}dx} $ given the substitution: $u = \sqrt x $

Tags: integration

My stab at it:

$\eqalign{
  & \int {{2 \over {\sqrt x (x - 4)}}dx}   \cr 
  & u = \sqrt x   \cr 
  & {{du} \over {dx}} = {1 \over 2}{x^{ - {1 \over 2}}} = {1 \over {2\sqrt x }}  \cr 
  & {{dx} \over {du}} = 2\sqrt x   \cr 
  & \int {f(x)dx}  = \int {{2 \over {\sqrt x (x - 4)}} \times 2\sqrt x {\rm{ }}du}   \cr 
  &  = \int {{{4\sqrt x } \over {\sqrt x (x - 4)}}du}   \cr 
  &  = \int {{{4u} \over {u({u^2} - 4)}}du}   \cr 
  &  = \int {{4 \over {({u^2} - 4)}}du}   \cr 
  &  = \int {{4 \over {({u^2} - 4)}}du}   \cr 
  &  = 4 \times {1 \over {2u}} \times \ln |({u^2} - 4)| + C  \cr 
  &  = {{2\ln |(x - 4)|} \over {\sqrt x }} + C \cr} $

---

My problem is the answer is:

$\ln |{{\sqrt x  - 2} \over {\sqrt x  + 2}}| + C$

I dont know how to simplify to reach this, this is most likely because I've probably made a mistake integrating. I am aware that you can reproduce the above answer using partial fractions to simplify the expression that is in terms of U and then integrate, but i was wondering if it was possible to duplicate the answer with my way of doing things..

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did just fine up to $\;\int \frac{4}{u^2-4}\,du\;\;$

Note that $$\int \frac{4}{u^2-4}du = \int \frac{4}{(u - 2)(u+2)}\,du = \int \left(\frac {A}{u - 2} + \frac{B}{u + 2} \right)\,du$$

That is, we can use *[partial fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction#Example_1)* to break our integral into the sum of two nicely integrable functions by simply solving for the numerators $A, B$.

In this case, $A$ and $B$ turn out to be "nice": To solve for $A, B$, note that $A(u + 2) + B(u - 2) = 4$.

Letting $u = 2 \implies  4A = 4 \implies A = 1$

Letting $u = -2 \implies -4B = 4 \implies B = -1$.

So our integral $$\int \left(\frac {A}{u - 2} + \frac{B}{u + 2} \right)\,du = \int \left(\frac 1{u-1} + \frac {-1}{u + 2} \right) \,du$$

Also note that for the solution you are given:
$$\ln \left|{{\sqrt x  - 2} \over {\sqrt x  + 2}}\right| + C = \ln\left|\sqrt{x} - 2\right| - \ln\left| \sqrt x + 2\right| + C$$

Comment: Is it not possible to integrate without splitting it into partial fractions?

Comment: The best route is to use partial fractions. You can not integrate $u^{-2}$ as you would if you had $\int \frac 1{u^2}$ because we can not treat the integrand like you would treat $\int \frac 4{u^2} - 1$ (we can't break up the denominator that way.)

Comment: I'm confused as my textbook says you can:

$$\int {{{2x} \over {{x^2} + 1}}} dx$$

it says you make y equal to the log of the denominator, in this case:

$$y = \ln |{x^2} + 1|$$

then differentiate to see what you get:

$${{dy} \over {dx}} = {{2x} \over {{x^2} - 1}}$$

If there is some discrepancy between the differentiated equation and y, then you just apply some adjustments to y to obtain the correct answer, why can't that apply in this case?

Comment: I know I have misunderstood something, could please explain what that is?

Comment: Yes, in your example just posted, notice that $(x^2 + 1)' = 2x$: that is, you have the derivative of the denominator in the numerator. In the problem at hand, which you are dealing with, we have only a constant: $4$, which is not the derivative of the denominator. $(u^2 - 4)' = 2u \neq 4$.

Comment: Ah! So you can only use this in the case that the numerator is the derivative of the denominator? Otherwise you should use partial fractions?

Comment: Exactly, Assad! ;-)

Comment: Yu've cleared up a big misunderstanding, thank you!

Comment: You are very welcome, Assad!

Comment: @amWhy: Very nice interaction and another thumbs up! +1

Answer (score 2):

When you reach: $$\int \frac{4}{u^2-4}du$$ you want to rewrite the denominator as: $$u^2-4=(u-2)(u+2)$$and use partial fractions.

Comment: Assad - Specifically, the step where you write down an attempt at that integral, you get it wrong. Try differentiating what you got and you'll find it's wrong because there's an extra term with a log.